# Show Coverage in github PR

Tags: python, github, pytest, travis-ci

We run tests on each pull request in github.

It would be very cool if the coverage would be visible if you are looking at the changes of a pull request.

While looking at the diff in the PR review I would like to see which line was covered and which line not.

We use pytest and travis.

I found this: https://github.com/TheKevJames/coveralls-python
But AFAIK this shows the coverage reports somewhere else, not in the "Files changed" tab of the PR.

This question is not about reaching a overall coverage of X percent. This question is about seeing which lines where covered and which lines where not covered.

Comment: so whats the question? You want code to show coverage in Github on a pull request?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri It would be very cool if the coverage would be visible if you are looking at the changes of a pull request.

Comment: have you tried the python package 'coverage' ?

Comment: maybe this will help ? https://about.codecov.io/blog/python-code-coverage-using-github-actions-and-codecov/

Comment: @JulianSilvestri codecov.io is a commercial service. I thought this is doable with scripting.

Comment: im sure it is, but you can attempt to learn how they do it ?

Comment: Take a look at [`coverage-diff`](https://pypi.org/project/coverage-diff/) or [`diff-cover`](https://diff-cover.readthedocs.io/). However, IMO the easiest approach is to have 100% code coverage and make tests fail if it drops below, e.g. running `pytest --cov-fail-under=100` in the CI (using the `pytest-cov` plugin).

Comment: @hoefling have you ever seen a project with 100% code coverage??

Comment: @be-chiller-too yep, a lot. What's your question, exactly? You need examples of good projects to learn from? Or are you questioning the usefulness of a full code coverage in general?

Comment: Code coverage is great, but I believe that the projects that reach 90% code coverage are really rare, let alone those with 100%

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can achieve this using Github Actions and the Github Check runs API.

Generic flow of the Github Action workflow will be:

1. Run `pytest` on the changed files and then generate `coverage` report.
2. Use `coverage` report to annotate the commit.

The generated report looks something like this:

[image: PR commit annotated using coverage report]

I have created a repository : [pytest-annotate-pr](https://github.com/amitds1997/pytest-annotate-pr) to demonstrate how this can be done. Note that, this is just a demonstration of how this can be done, and it's far from production ready. For example, this currently only works when a commit is pushed in a PR :) It does not work when branches are merged into `main`. The above screenshot is from [one of the PR](https://github.com/amitds1997/pytest-annotate-pr/pull/1/commits/49c59556ab9c2bdcdef5789adf635e4a68aa0d8a) raised against `main`.

If you work on this and make a production ready workflow, please consider making it into a Github Action.

Answer (score 3):

A partial solution: In one of the projects I work in, we have a [codecov action](https://github.com/marketplace/codecov) set up. This action [has a feature](https://docs.codecov.io/docs/github-checks) to annotate lines that were not covered in the "Files changed" tab:

[image: Codecov annotation in the Files changed tab]

This only shows you which lines were *not* covered, but maybe that's better than nothing?

Edit: I just now noticed that Julian already suggested codecov in the comments and that you said you wanted something non-commercial. I can only add there that codecov is free for public repos as well as teams with up to five members. If you have a private repo and a bigger team and do not want to pay for this service, this doesn't help you.

I think I should still keep the answer here in case someone finds this question when searching for a solution for an open source project.

Comment: Thank you. This answer is better than nothing. Maybe I should switch to gitlab, since I prefer usually "do it yourself" to "buy".

Answer (score 0):

You can output the code coverage into the README file, this way you will see the code coverage when you are in the "Files changed" tab AND when you access the project's page.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear: I want to see which lines are covered and which lines are not.

Comment: I don't think you can do this, it's the purpose of a coverage report, but you do this offline before pushing your code.